# Find point on Line with same distances to two given points with additional previous distance

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Hello fellows mathematicians. I have a quite problem in 2D Euclidian Space I can't solve for some time.
Let's look at it:
[image: Diagram]
All I need is to get a position of point $T$ which lies somewhere on line $AB$
I defined in form of Linear Interpolation as $T = A + t(B-A)$ where $t$ is variable I'm looking for.

My condition is that the distance from $O_1$ to $T$ + $d1$ is must be equal to distance from $O_2$ to $T$ + $d2$

In this case I'm trying to solve equation for $t$.
$$
\begin{align}
|T-O_1|+d_1 & = & |T-O_2|+d_2  \\
|A + t(B-A)-O_1|+d_1 & = & |A + t(B-A)-O_2|+d_2 \\
\text{let's assume we shifter system before so $A = (0, 0)$}\\
|tB-O_1|+d_1 & = & |tB-O_2|+d_2 \\
\end{align}
$$

which soon become a madness and I don't know how to get out of this madness.
How could I get my point T?

Comment: Point $T$ is the intersection between line $AB$ and the hyperbola with foci $O_1$, $O_2$ passing through $S$.

Comment: But the algebra is not so bad after all: 1) carry $d_2$ to LHS; 2) square both sides; 3) simplify, isolate the remaining norm and square again.

Comment: well  in reality, because I'm working on unfolded 3D meshes, when unfolded, there are two points $S$, $S_1$ and $S_2$ which in 3D are the same point, but because of unfolding different faces, I end up with different position, but thank you so much, I somehow haven't thought about squaring it the was you suggested, I'll try it and then post it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so here is a solution with deduction.
[![Diagram][1]][1]
Let's make some statements and assumptions first.

- we assume that $A = (0, 0)$ because we can shift entire coordinate system.
- let use following:
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \text{let} \ \ & X_n = |tB-O_n| \\
  \text{then}\ \  & X_{n}^{2} =\ t^{2} B^{2} -2t( B \cdot O_{n}) +O_{n}^{2} \tag{1}\label{X_n}
  \end{align}
  $$
- let's look for $t$ in equation $T=A+t( B-A)$
- equation that must be fullfilled is : $X_1 + d_1 = X_2 + d_2$

So let's start
$$
T=A+t( B-A) \notag\\
\begin{array}{ r c l }
|T-O_{1} |\ +\ d_{1} & = & |T-O_{2} |\ +\ d_{2}\\
|A+t( B-A) \ -\ O_{1} |\ +\ d_{1} & = & |A+t( B-A) \ -\ O_{2} |\ +\ d_{2}
\end{array} \notag\\
let\ A =\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix} \ \text{(by shifting entire coordinate system)} \notag\\
\begin{array}{ r c l c }
|tB\ -\ O_{1} |\ +\ d_{1} & = & |tB\ -\ O_{2} |\ +\ d_{2} & \\
|tB\ -\ O_{1} |\ +\ d_{1} -d_{2} & = & |tB\ -\ O_{2} |\  & \\
( |tB\ -\ O_{1} |\ +\ d_{1} -d_{2})^{2} & = & |tB\ -\ O_{2} |^{2} & \text{based on \eqref{X_n}}\\
( X_{1} \ +\ d_{1} -d_{2})^{2} & = & X_{2}^{2} & \\
X_{1}^{2} +2d_{1} X_{1} -2d_{2} X_{1} +d_{1}^{2} +d_{2}^{2} -2d_{1} d_{2} & = & X_{2}^{2} & 
\end{array} \notag\\
$$

$$\begin{array}{ r c l c }
X_{1}^{2} +\mathbf{2d_{1} X_{1} -2d_{2} X_{1}} +d_{1}^{2} +d_{2}^{2} -2d_{1} d_{2} & = & X_{2}^{2} & \\
X_{1}( 2d_{1} -2d_{2}) & = & X_{2}^{2} -X_{1}^{2} -d_{1}^{2} -d_{2}^{2} +2d_{1} d_{2} & \\
{\textstyle X_{1}} & = & \frac{X_{2}^{2} -X_{1}^{2}\mathbf{-d_{1}^{2} -d_{2}^{2} +2d_{1} d_{2}}}{\mathbf{2d_{1} -2d_{2}}} & \text{let define constants}\\
C_{1} & = & 2d_{1} d_{2} -d_{1}^{2} -d_{2}^{2} \  & \\
C_{1} & = & -\left( d_{1}^{2} -2d_{1} d_{2} +d_{2}^{2}\right) & \\
C_{1} & = & -( d_{1} -d_{2})^{2} & \\
C_{2} &  & 2d_{1} -2d_{2} \ =\ 2( d_{1} -d_{2}) & \\
X_{1} & = & \frac{X_{2}^{2} -X_{1}^{2} +C_{1}}{C_{2}} & \text{expand using \eqref{X_n})}\\
X_{1} & = & \frac{ \begin{array}{l}
\ \ t^{2} B^{2} -2t( B \cdot O_{2}) +O_{2}^{2} -\ \ \ \ \ \ \\
-t^{2} B^{2} +2t( B \cdot O_{1}) -O_{1}^{2} \ +\ C_{1}
\end{array}}{C_{2}} & \\
X_{1} & = & \frac{\ \mathbf{2} t(\mathbf{B\cdot O_{1} -B\cdot O_{2}}) +\mathbf{O_{2}^{2} -O_{1}^{2} \ +\ C_{1}}}{\mathbf{C_{2}}} & \text{lets define more constants}\\
C_{3} & = & \frac{O_{2}^{2} -O_{1}^{2} \ +\ C_{1}}{C_{2}} & \tag{2}\label{C_3}\\
C_{4} & = & \frac{2( B \cdot O_{1} -B\cdot O_{2})}{C_{2}} & \\
X_{1} & = & \ tC_{4} +C_{3} & \\
X_{1}^{2} & = & \ ( tC_{4} +C_{3})^{2} & \\
t^{2} B^{2} -2t( B \cdot O_{1}) +O_{1}^{2} & = & \ t^{2} C_{4}^{2} +2tC_{4} C_{3} +C_{3}^{2} & \\
t^{2}\mathbf{B^{2}} -\mathbf{2} t\mathbf{( B\cdot O_{1})} +\mathbf{O_{1}^{2}} & = & t^{2}\mathbf{C_{4}^{2}} +\mathbf{2} t\mathbf{C_{4} C_{3}} +\mathbf{C_{3}^{2}} & \\
t^{2} a+tb+c & = & 0 & \\
where &  &  & \\
a & = & \left( B^{2} -C_{4}^{2}\right) & \\
b & = & -2( B \cdot O_{1} +C_{4} C_{3}) & \\
c & = & O_{1}^{2} -C_{3}^{2} & \\
t & = & \frac{-b\ \pm \sqrt{b^{2} -4ac}}{2a} & 
\end{array}\\$$

There are also some observations.

- There are only two cases when there is no real solution:

  - If $d_1 = d_2$ then $C_2 = 0$ and so $C_3$ and $C_4$\eqref{C_3} can't be computed.(division by zero).

    - In this case we can find easily the point $T$ as intersection of perpendicular bisector of $O_1O_2$  and $AB$ Line.
  - if Discriminant of Quadratic Equation $D \leq 0 $. This is met when $|O_1 -O_2| \leq |d_1 - d_2|$. (I won't prove it in here for now).

**So the solution is:**

1. if $d_1 = d_2$ then the point $T$ is at intersection of perpendicular bisector of $O_1O_2$  and $AB$ Line.
   $$\begin{align}
   C_{1} & = & -( d_{1} -d_{2})^{2} & \\
   C_{2} & = & 2( d_{1} -d_{2}) & \\
   C_{3} & = & \frac{O_{2}^{2} -O_{1}^{2} \ +\ C_{1}}{C_{2}} & \\
   C_{4} & = & \frac{2( B \cdot O_{1} -B\cdot O_{2})}{C_{2}} & \\
   a & = & \left( B^{2} -C_{4}^{2}\right) & \\
   b & = & -2( B \cdot O_{1} +C_{4} C_{3}) & \\
   c & = & O_{1}^{2} -C_{3}^{2} & \\
   D & = & b^2 - 4ac & \\
   \end{align}$$
2. if $D \leq 0$, then there are no points in same distance. \
   $$\begin{align}
   t_1 & = & \frac{-b+\sqrt{D}}{2a} \\
   t_2 & = & \frac{-b-\sqrt{D}}{2a} \\
   T_1 & = & A + t_1(B-A) \\
   T_2 & = & A + t_2(B-A) \\
   \end{align}$$

There are also conditions (based on our deduction when the given point is not a solution)
$$C_n = (t_n C_4+C_3≥0) ∧ (|t_n B-O_1|+d_1-d_2)$$
this condition is because of steps where we are squaring the equation(if the non '$X$ part' is negative, then the given number is not a solution ).
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfQSd.png